# How to get the user who entered the command in onButtonInteraction

Tags: java, discord-jda

[image]

Tried
`event.getMessage().getReferencedMessage().getUser()`, but gave a Nullpointerexception
I tried to get it by the `event.getJDA().getUserByTag()`, but if there is a space in the tag, it throws a NullPointException

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [message.getInteraction()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getInteraction()). This may look like a message reply, but the interaction is not a message itself.

Example:

```java
User user = message.getInteraction().getUser();
```